# how can i retrieve the remote Environment property for a COM+ component

Tags: com+

I have a huge list of COM+ components and need to make a catalog with all the important values, such as the remote Environment, but i cant find this property.

this its what I have tried so far without success

```
    Set comAdmin = CreateObject("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog")
    Set applications = comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications")
    applications.Populate

    For Each app In applications
        ' WScript.Echo "Application: " & app.Value("Name")

        Set components = applications.GetCollection("Components", app.Key)
        components.Populate

        For Each component In components
            On Error Resume Next

            WScript.Echo "Application: " & app.Value("Name")
            WScript.Echo "Component: " & component.Name
            WScript.Echo "DLL: " & component.Value("DLL")
            WScript.Echo "RemoteServer: " & component.RemoteServer
            WScript.Echo "RemoteEnvironment: " & component.Value("RemoteEnvironment")
        Next
    Next
```